# JS - Holding DOM elements in variables

Tags: javascript, html

I need some clarification, as I have managed to confuse myself. Let's say we have the following code:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var words = textarea.value;
console.log(words);
}
```

This code runs by first gathering the DOM elements (the button and textarea) into their respective variables. Later in the code, when the button is pressed, `textarea.value` is placed into the variable `words`. Fair enough right?

My question is why isn't nothing logged into the console? The textarea variable is created and stored from the DOM after the page loads, which pressumably would be before the user had time to write anything into the textarea. This would mean that `textarea.value` should equal `''` (nothing), as opposed to the string in the textarea at the time that the button was pressed by the user.

If anyone could clear this up for me that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: What happens when you click the button without typing anything? Doesn't it log to the console?

Comment: @MunamYousuf When the button is pressed it does log something technically, which is an empty value (`''`). So although we don't see anything the action of logging something to the console still takes place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This would mean that `textarea.value` should equal `''` (nothing), as opposed to the string in the textarea at the time that the button was pressed by the user.

Nope!

The `value` property of an input element updates dynamically based on user input or other code that changes it. It matters when you access the `value` property. Because you access it when the button is clicked, the value set on the element is read when the button is clicked.

If however you did something like this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
var words = document.getElementById("myButton").value;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(words);
}
```

Then the value would be read earlier (likely being blank, but could be a default value, and auto-save variable, or something else it was set to earlier), and changes by the user would be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 2 jsfiddles.

```
<input id = "myTextarea"/>
<button id= "myButton" type="submit"> test </button>
var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var words = textarea.value;
    console.log(words);
});
```

In the [first](https://jsfiddle.net/bsty86pb/1/) one, you are capturing the value of the text area inside the on click event. Thus, you get the value that has already been entered.

```
<input id = "myTextarea"/>
<button id= "myButton" type="submit"> test </button>
var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(words);
});
```

In the [second](https://jsfiddle.net/bsty86pb/2/) fiddle, you are capturing the value as soon as the DOM is loaded without waiting for the click event to happen. Thus, the value that prints in console is blank.

Thus, whether you will see the value entered or nothing at all depends on when you capture the value, after the event happens or right after the DOM is loaded. Hope this helps.